# Silverlight vs Sliverlight - typo or real thing?

Tags: discussion, edits, tags, spelling

Is there a product called Sliverlight, possibly a spoof, knockoff, or add-on, or are there that many people who mistype Silverlight?  Before I go off randomly changing Sliverlight to Silverlight, I'd want to make sure it's not a real product.  I noticed there are [4 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sliverlight) tagged "sliverlight" as well.

Comment: I was staring at the question title for 30 seconds and was thinking it's a joke question till the bitmap matching circuitry in my brain recognized the difference.

Comment: With the font I'm looking at, it's hard to tell the difference. Possibly why it's undetected for so long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the question text, those all look like spelling errors and should be `SilverLight`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm mostly a Java/Unix person at the moment.  Haven't done MS dev in 10+ years.